# Are countably compactly generated spaces paracompact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, paracompactness

A space X is *countably compactly generated* if it can be written as countable direct limit of compact Hausdorff spaces.

Are countably compactly generated spaces paracompact spaces? Do we have partition of unity for countably compactly generated spaces?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that each countably compactly generated space $X$ is $\sigma$-compact; so if $X$ is regular then $X$ is Lindelof and, therefore, paracompact.

Moreover, it seems that a Hausdorff space is countably compactly generated iff it is a $k_\omega$-space. I remind that a topological space $X$ is defined to be a *$k_\omega$-space* if there is a countable cover $\mathcal K$ of $X$ by compact subsets of $X$, determining the topology of $X$ in the sense that a subset $U$ of $X$ is open in $X$ if and only if the intersection $U\cap K$ is open in $K$ for any compact set $K\in\mathcal K$. According to [FT], each Hausdorff $k_\omega$-space is normal.

[FT] S.P. Franklin, B.V. Smith Thomas. A survey of $k_\omega$-spaces // *Topology Proc.* **2** (1977),
111--124.